# Swift Firebase -How to generate different .childByAutoId keys when using Fan Out

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have a chat system inside my app. When the user presses send to send the message data to different nodes inside the database -it works fine. The issue I'm having is since I'm using fan out I generate the `.childByAutoId`key  before the data is sent. The user presses a send button to start the process but it's always the same exact `.childByAutoId` key so I'm just overwriting the previous message data. If the user pops the vc and comes back to it then a new key is created but obviously that's terrible ux for a messaging system?

How can I generate different `.childByAutoId` keys every time the user presses send to fan out?

```
@obj func sendMessageButtonPressed() {

    // ***here's the problem, every time they press send, it's the same exact childByAutoId().key so I'm just overwriting the previous data at the messages/messageId path
    guard let messageId = FirebaseManager.Database.database().reference().child("messages")?.childByAutoId().key else { return }

    var messageIdDict: [String: Any] = [messageId: "1"]

    var messageDict = [String: Any]() // has the fromId, toId, message, and timeStamp on it

    let messageIdPath = "messages/\(messageId)"
    let fromIdPath = "user-messages/\(currentUserId)"
    let toIdPath = "user-messages/\(toId)"

    var fanOutDict = [String: Any]()
    fanOutDict.updateValue(messageDict, forKey: messageIdPath)
    fanOutDict.updateValue(messageIdDict, forKey: fromIdPath)
    fanOutDict.updateValue(messageIdDict, forKey: toIdPath) 

    let rootRef = Database.database().reference()
    rootRef?.updateChildValues(fanOutDict)
}
```

Comment: whys that better? with childbyautoid the date is automatically managed by firebase

Comment: Every time you call `childByAutoId()` is generates a new unique (and ever-increasing) ID. Are you saying that you get the same value when you call `sendMessageButtonPressed` multiple times?

Comment: @excitedmicrobe It's quite idiomatic to use `childByAutoId` for auto-generating *auto-incrementing* keys in Firebase Realtime Database. While generating your own random keys is not wrong, I would love to hear what makes you say they are way better. It might even make a good question.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen I found out what the problem is. Since I'm using the fanout method it doesn't;t update what's at the node by adding the new data it's overwriting what was originally there. So I do get a new key but the fanout overwrites what was  previously at the user-messages node.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem wasn't a new key was not getting generated. @FrankvanPuffelen pointed out in th comments that a new key should get generated every time which is exactly what was happening.

The problem was the fanout was overwriting what was originally written at these 2 paths:

```
let fromIdPath = "user-messages/\(currentUserId)"
let toIdPath = "user-messages/\(toId)"
```

It appeared the key was the same because the data kept getting overwritten.

The way I was generating the key works fine